# Problema capturar info en formulario html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jquery, json

tengo un inconveniente. tengo un formulario modal hecho en HTML, capturo esa info y la envió utilizando json a un archivo que ingresa esa info a una base de datos, el inconveniente es que no me esta capturando la info del formulario. probé con algunas alternativas pero me sigue dando el mismo error. Me podrían ayudar por favor.

Codigo del formulario HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCRUD" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>  
        <!--cambiar nombre formulario-->
    <form id="formPersonas">    
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="anillamador" class="col-form-label">Anillamador:</label>
            <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="anillamador">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cedula" class="col-form-label">Cédula:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula">
            </div>                
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket" class="col-form-label">Ticket:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ticket">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label">Fecha:</label>
            <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="fecha" readonly value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\ H:i");?>" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="requerimiento" class="col-form-label">Requerimiento:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="requerimiento">
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="escalado" class="col-form-label">Escalado:</label>
            <select name="escalado" id="escalado" class="col-form-label">
            <option value="si">Si </option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
            </select> 
            </div>           
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-dark">Guardar</button>
        </div>
    </form>    
    </div>
</div>
```

código donde capturo la info del formulario

```
    $("#formPersonas").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    //nombre de los input en el formulario   
    var anillamador = $.trim($("#anillamador").val());
    var cedula = $.trim($("#cedula").val());
    var ticket = $.trim($("#ticket").val());
    var fecha = $.trim($("#fecha").val());
    var requerimiento = $.trim($("#requerimiento").val());
    var escalado = $.trim($("#escalado").val());     
   // echo(anillamador); 
    $.ajax({ 
        //URL para enviar y recibir datos
        url: "bd/crud.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {anillamador:anillamador, cedula:cedula, ticket:ticket, fecha:fecha, requerimiento:requerimiento, escalado:escalado, id:id, opcion:opcion},
        success: function(data){  
            console.log(data);// para ver el resultado que se recibe 
            id = data[0].id; // posible error         
            anillamador = data[0].anillamador;
            cedula = data[0].cedula;
            ticket = data[0].ticket;
            fecha = data[0].fecha;
            requerimiento = data[0].requerimiento;
            escalado = data[0].escalado;
            if(opcion == 1){tablaPersonas.row.add([id,anillamador,cedula,ticket,fecha,requerimiento,escalado]).draw();}
            else{tablaPersonas.row(fila).data([id,anillamador,cedula,ticket,fecha,requerimiento,escalado]).draw();}            
        }        
    }); 
    //nombre modal 
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("hide");    
    
});
```

código donde se realiza el ingreso de la info en la base de datos

```
    <?php
//include_once '../bd/conexion.php';
include_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();
// Recepción de los datos enviados mediante POST desde el JS   
// isset determina si una variable esta definida y no es nula
          // condicioc              si es verdadero (?)       si es falso (:)
$anillamador = (isset($_POST['anillamador'])) ? $_POST['anillamador'] : '';
$cedula = (isset($_POST['cedula'])) ? $_POST['cedula'] : '';
$ticket = (isset($_POST['ticket'])) ? $_POST['ticket'] : '';
$fecha = (isset($_POST['fecha'])) ? $_POST['fecha'] : '';
$requerimiento = (isset($_POST['requerimiento'])) ? $_POST['requerimiento'] : '';
$escalado = (isset($_POST['escalado'])) ? $_POST['escalado'] : '';
$opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';
$id = (isset($_POST['id_registro'])) ? $_POST['id_registro'] : '';

switch($opcion){
    case 1: //alta
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO registros (anillamador, cedula, ticket, fecha, requerimiento, escalado) VALUES('$anillamador', '$cedula', '$ticket', '$fecha', '$requerimiento', '$escalado') ";           
        // se prepara la consulta
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        // se ejecuta el resultado
        $resultado->execute(); 

        $consulta = "SELECT id_registro, anillamador, cedula, ticket, fecha, requerimiento, escalado FROM registros ORDER BY id_registros DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
    print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //enviar el array final en formato json a JS
$conexion = NULL;
```

al abrir la consola en el navegador me aparece este error
[image: Error cuando quiero agregar a la BDD]

Comment: no veo donde declaras `data` en tu javascrip

Answer (score -1):

en tu archivo donde haces el llamado a la bd (ajax), veo que tienes declaradas las variables para obtener los datos, y esas mismas las usas para guardar las respuestas, pero nunca declaras 'id'